# Generating setter for a created Object in the main Class in INTELLIJ IDEA IDE

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, setter

Can I generate a setter for an object created in the main class

1. Created class X
2. class X has dozens of variables with there setter and getter methods (No problem)
3. Crated object y from class X in another class
4. I want to set the variables of object y within the other class

Does intelliJ IDE have a generator for setters to be y.set1() .. y.setn() instead of writing them down tens of times.

Comment: For IDE IntelliJ IDEA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not directly, however you may want to create a constructor which sets all fields (perhaps messy with `dozens` of fields, but doable nonetheless...)

- go into class X, hit Insert to get the `Generate` popup, hit Enter to select `Constructor`, then ctrl-A for All, Enter

There is also the possibility to write an `Action` in a small custom IntelliJ plugin to do this, if you think the effort it is worth the benefit...

Otherwise, if you are dealing with objects with many fields, the `Builder` design pattern might be worth a look.

[Example of Builder pattern](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/builder-design-pattern-in-java.html)

There is an IntelliJ refactoring for this!

Create your constructor using all fields (like above), and from the `Refactor` menu (right click), choose `Replace Constructor With Builder`.

Then look for a new class named `XBuilder` and use it like so...

```
X y = new XBuilder.setA(1).setB(2).setC(3).createX();
```

Comment: Thank you for the Builder Pattern hint !!

Answer (score 8):

I was using the constructor trick, but found a better way (to me) :

Go to the "Structure" view for the class you'd like to generate the setters for, and sort members from a to z.

Then you can copy / paste setters

[image]

Now with a little bit of multi line editing (alt + left click) you 'll be able to add the missing parts of the line.

[image]

Hope that help.

Answer (score -1):

There is a plugin for that. [GenerateAllSetter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9360-generateallsetter)

To install the plugin, go to:

- Preferences -> Plugins -> Browse Repositories...
- Search for: **GenerateAllSetter** and click in the Install button.
  [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GM3j1.png)
- Restart Intellij.

Usage:

- Just click the variable you want to generate the setters and then `Alt + Enter`. There will be an option to "generate all setter":
  [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLPkH.png)
- After clicking the "generate all setter" option, all setter of a created Object will be generated: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNVd7.png)